# Debug as root jetBrains Rider

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

Is there a way to debug a project with root privileges in Rider like in Clion ? In CLion there is next settings but in Rider there isn't: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/debug-as-root.html#elevation